# I have an equation involving a polynomial function with coefficients that are exponentials.

Tags: calculus, roots

> To solve: $$2\left[(2^{x}-1)\left(x^{2}-1\right)+(2^{x^{2}-1}-1)x\right]= 0$$

There are three obvious solutions by observation, $x = -1, 0, 1$, and the graph of the function (red font) and its first derivative (blue font) look like this:[image: y-vs-x, and y'-vs-x]

How can I prove that these are the *only* zeroes of the function?

Comment: Why do you keep this factor $2$ ?

Comment: @Yves A slight oversight, I graphed the function and printed the image including the factor of 2, then didn't bother to replot it and print a new image. Thank you for your answer, it is most enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2^x-1)(x+1)(x-1)$$ has exactly three roots, at $-1,0,1$, by cancelling the three factors, and

$$x(2^{(x+1)(x-1)}-1)$$ as well.

Then it is easy to see that these two functions have the same signs everywhere, and their sum can only be zero at the common roots.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If you prove the derivative has 2 roots, by Rolle's theorem, you are limited to 3 roots of the original function, say $r<s<t$, with a root of the derivative between each pair, i.e. in $(r,s)$ and another in $(s,t)$.

In other words, if there were a fourth root, $x <r$, say, you would have to have another root of the derivative in $(x,r)$...

Comment: Thank you. My problem then, I think, would be to prove that the derivative has *only* the two roots indicated by its graph. As with the three roots of the function itself, I am again not sure how to proceed.